# Sequentially renaming a file on upload, based on the existing files in directory

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

I am using this (php) upload code I found online as an image upload form.

I realize there are already a lot of questions/answers on the site about 'renaming files' on upload, and I have researched them quite a bit.

So far... none of them seem to address specifically what I would like to do.

Hopefully this is doable through adjusting the code I am using somehow.

Ultimately... I would like to to be able to upload individual files (not multiple), and have the files automatically named with a simple, numeric digit, such as; 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5, etc...

No prefix and no extension. Just a numerical value for the name.

However, I would like the code to check the target directory first to scan for what file 'names' already exist.

So if the existing files in the directory are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5... the new file would automatically be sequentially named 6, and so on.

But if the existing files in the directory are 1, 2, 4, and 5 (where no 3 is present), the new file would be uploaded as 3, to preserve a sequential order.

Or, for my particular needs, I wouldn't even mind if all of the images in the directory were renamed with the new upload. Essentially shifting the order so the numeric sequence is preserved.

This is the upload code I am currently using:

```
<?php

$target_dir = "userImages/userID/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

  if($check !== false) {

    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";

    $uploadOk = 1;

  
  } else {

    echo "File is not an image.";

    $uploadOk = 0;

  
  }
}

// Check if file already exists

if (file_exists($target_file)) {

  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";

  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {

  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";

  $uploadOk = 0;


}

// Allow certain file formats

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"

&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {

  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";

  $uploadOk = 0;


}


// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error

if ($uploadOk == 0) {

  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file


} else {

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has 
been uploaded.";

  } else {

    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

  
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this function, it checks if the files in the directory are not named consecutively then will rename to have it always numbered, the function returns the next number for the new uploaded file

```
function get_next_file_number($target_dir)  {

    $files = scandir($target_dir);
    if (false === $files) {         // If false then is not a directory, you could throw an Exception here
        return -1;
    }
    $counter = 0;
    unset($files[0], $files[1]);    // Delete the . and .. from array
    natsort($files);                // Important! Sort file names naturally
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        ++$counter;
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name = $file_info['filename'];
        $extension = $file_info['extension'];
        if ($file_name != $counter) {
            $old_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
            $new_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $counter . "." . $extension;
            if (!file_exists($new_name)) {
                rename($old_name, $new_name);
            }
            else {
                // Oops trying to rename to a file that already exists, this shouldn't happen!
            }
            //echo "renamed: " . $old_name . " to " . $new_name, "<br>";
        }
    }
    return $counter + 1;
}
```

How to implement it?

```
// .....
// You can check the returned value, if it is -1 you know there was an error
$next_number = get_next_file_number($target_dir);
$new_target_file = $target_dir . $next_number . "." . $imageFileType;
// Here you can make sure the file does not exists... just to make sure...
// Here move the uploaded file with the next number
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $new_target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
}
// .....
```

Comment: This sounds pretty awesome. I'm afraid I haven't the foggiest clue how to implement this into the existing code. I tried a few different ways and am making a mess.

Comment: Updated the answer with the implementation...

Comment: Thank you! You rock. The only issue I am having now, is that the "." and the (file type) extension are still saving as well. For example, it's saving as 1.jpg when I want it to only save as 1, without the "." or extension. I tried editing this line, but it still shows up:  $new_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $counter . "." . $extension;

Comment: If you want it without the extension just remove `. "." . $extension` in `$new_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $counter . "." . $extension;` and remove `. "." . $imageFileType;` in `$new_target_file = $target_dir . $next_number . "." . $imageFileType;`